# 'tr' command on linux: LF to CRLF not possible?

Tags: linux, command-line

```
echo "foo" > test.txt
```

`od -c test.txt` shows me `f o o \n` as expected.

Now I try to convert the LFs to CRLFs and check the result after the pipe:

```
tr '\n' '\r\n' < test.txt | od -c
```

But the output is `f o o \r`

How did that happen? Why does the program ignore my `\n` and translates to just `\r` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` replaces single characters by single characters.

> `tr [-c|-C] [-s] string1 string2`
>
> […]
>
> If `string2` is present, each input character found in the array specified by `string1` shall be replaced by the character in the same relative position in the array specified by `string2`.

<sup>[(source)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html)</sup>

In you case the first character from the first string (`\n`) is translated to the first character from the second string (`\r`).

You need another tool to insert more than one character in place of one. Example with `sed`:

```
sed 's/$/\r/' < test.txt | od -c
```

Or a specialized tool to handle line endings in particular:

```
unix2dos < test.txt | od -c
```

Comment: Or just remove the \r char. E.g. ``tr -d '\r'``

Comment: @JonShipman The OP wants to *add*.